# How to make DateTime from API is ticking like clock?

Tags: flutter, dart

I get time from API. It comes in Unix time format, I converted it to hours, minutes, seconds, but I can't make it tick like a regular clock, that is, hours, minutes, and seconds should go and be on the screen like a regular clock. It turns out to get only "stationary" time from the API

I tried to use streams, but it only turned out to update minutes,but not seconds every 60 seconds. After that, I found that I can use the standard `dart async` package built into flutter and update the data every time with the help of setState, but this only works if I use the time from the device, and not from the API. After that, I thought that the `timer_builder` package could help me, but I still can’t make the time from the API move like a regular clock

My code now is like this:

```
child: StreamBuilder<String?>(
  stream: streamGPSTime,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    DateTime y = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data?.toString() ??
            '2022-08-04T16:16:51+03:00')
        .toLocal();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss');
    var timeString = formatter.format(y);
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      print(timeString);
      return TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1),
          builder: (context) {
        return Align(
          child: Text(
            timeString,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: GoogleFonts.courierPrime(fontSize: 46),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [analog_clock](https://pub.dev/packages/analog_clock) package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)?

It has a `datetime` option that you might be able to help you set the time.

Comment: It was backend issue. If you can't make clock ticking by seconds, only minutes change, so highly recommend to ask your backend devs to found out what is going on and how they coded time